# Cruisecontrol.Net reporting incorrectly reporting build status

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We've been having some issues with CCnet 1.5.7256.1 recently where some builds are running and failing but being reported as Successful builds. The build logs show the exception/failure status but the dashboard is still displaying green ticks and Success.

Obviously this is a concern as failed builds are going unnoticed.

Has anyone else had this problem?

I've posted on the ccnet-user google group here - http://groups.google.com.ag/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/4190a19b0fee57b3

Comment: I've seen this as well.  Not sure what is causing it.  Have you tried turning on debug logging and see if anything gets output in ccnet.log?

Answer (score 1):

give the errorlevel command to your builds.
if its a batch file give a command of finding errorlevel after every build command. This will return the cruise control failed status which will make the CC build status failed.

Command is:
If %Errorlevel% is neq 0 than exit /b errorlevel